# Jenkins job unable to pass integer parameters into python script during build

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jenkins, boto3

I have a python script that I tested on an EC2 instance, which works perfectly fine on the server but when I try to pass the same parameters from Jenkins job as shown below. I get the error message:

> > Security Group Created **sg-ca09bcae** in vpc **vpc-d79691b9**. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./create_sg.py", line 32, in 
> >         'FromPort': int(FROM_PORT_1.strip("")), 
> >     marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'within' Build
> >     step 'Execute shell'

[image: Jenkins Job Parameters]

I'm pretty sure the error is because of the string parameter that I'm passing through Jenkins parameters but there isn't an option to send both From and To ports as integers in jenkins parameters.

How can I set the parameters to an integer within Jenkins build job?

Python code to create SG:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
region = "us-west-1"

VPC_ID=sys.argv[1]
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[2]
DESCRIPTION=sys.argv[3]
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[4]
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[5]
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[6]
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[7]


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2.describe_vpcs()

vpc_id = VPC_ID

try:
    response = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName=SECURITY_GROUP_NAME,Description=DESCRIPTION,VpcId=VPC_ID)
    security_group_id = response['GroupId']
    print('Security Group Created %s in vpc %s.' % (security_group_id, vpc_id))

    data = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=security_group_id,
        IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': IP_PROTOCOL_1,
             'FromPort': int(FROM_PORT_1),
             'ToPort': int(TO_PORT_1),
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': CIDR_IP_1}]}
        ]
    )
    print('Ingress Successfully Set %s' % data)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

@nosklo, Suggested I try the following:

```
VPC_ID=sys.argv[1] 
SECURITY_GROUP_NAME=sys.argv[2]
DESCRIPTION=' '.join(sys.argv[3:-4])
IP_PROTOCOL_1=sys.argv[-4]
FROM_PORT_1=sys.argv[-3]
TO_PORT_1=sys.argv[-2] 
CIDR_IP_1=sys.argv[-1]
```

With which the ports are listed as 0 vs the values that I passed in the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't any way to test this, but the error message shows the invalid `int` value as the word "within". That suggests that the Description parameter is being substituted directly onto a command line without any quoting, so that `sys.argv[5]` would indeed be the string "within". You might try including quotes around the description: `"Security group within dev environment".

Comment: it's not the description that's having an issue.

The script works fine, when we run it manually. 

Having issues when we pass the parameters (FROM_PORT_1 &
TO_PORT_1) via Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `os.getenv`:

```
import os

VPC_ID = os.getenv('VPC_ID')

print(VPC_ID)
```

should work.

Comment: The script works fine, when we run it manually. 

Having issues when we pass the parameters (FROM_PORT_1 &
TO_PORT_1) via Jenkins.

Comment: I believe the way that you're accessing the arguments now is not correct, I would try to use the suggested method for all environment variables.